# PowerShell Text-Replace Pwd with special char

Tags: string, powershell, special-characters

I have a password with special char (in a PSObject):

```
  "Pwd" = "ng%h?k^jh$ert"
```

Now to login I need to handle this as a string!
How do I protect e.g. $ ($ert) and all the other special char for being evaluated, interpreted, or changed?

Thanks in advance
Gooly

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try using single quotes instead and see how far that takes you.

```
"Pwd" = 'ng%h?k^jh$ert'
```

If the password contained the character ' you'd be in a similar problem again though but that could be handled with escape chars;

```
"Pwd" = "ng%h?`'k^jh`$ert"
```